# Not returning the right value of the dictionary

Tags: python

i am pretty new to dictionaries and i have a problem with this code. I don't understand why its always outpuing the value 0. it's like if anything i enter goes into this else. The only reason it should display 0 is if the word is missing from the list

```
if item in resultat.keys():
    print(item, ": {}".format(resultat[item]))
else:
    print(item, ": 0")
```

Exemple of the dictionnary i am using that is imported from a txt file:

```
pommes : 54
bananes
oranges : 30
```

Exemple of input

```
item.py data1.txt pommes
```

Exemple of erroneous output i am getting:

```
pommes : 0
```

exptected output

```
pommes : 54
```

This is my code im working on.

```
import sys

def ligne(texte, item):
    try:
        with open(texte) as ouvrir:
            mots_dict = {}
            lecture = ouvrir.readlines()
            for line in lecture:
                line = line.strip('\n')
                try:
                    mot, nombre = line.split(':')[1], int(line.split(':')[2])
                except IndexError:
                    continue
                if mot not in mots_dict.keys():
                    mots_dict[mot] = nombre
                elif mot == item:
                    raise Exception('La ligne {} est un doublon.'.format(line))
            return mots_dict
    except IOError:
        print("Le fichier", texte, "n'existe pas.")
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Show the raw `resultat` dictionary, and an example `item`.

Comment: That `except IndexError: continue` is hiding the error you're getting on every line of the file.  When the `.split(':')` works, the two pieces have indexes 0 and 1, not 1 and 2 as you're trying to use.

Comment: ok jason so you just recommend me to remove the except?

Comment: @MartinBergeron I think that the posted answer has a shot at fixing the issue since you could have keys in the dictionary that contain whitespace and therefore don't match your input words. However, the only way to know this is if you actually print out your dict and include it in your question. Until then, we could be going off on tangents.

Comment: my dict has been integrated i am sorry for the confusion but when i meant exemple of a list it is actualy my dict. i have modified the question. thanks you

Comment: That's not a dictionary. I mean the actual dictionary object printed. `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}` etc.

Comment: And not hand written but copy/pasted exactly the way it is printed from your code.

Comment: Print and show the sys.argv and resultat

Comment: Also, @jasonharper was not suggesting you remove the `try`/`except`, he was saying that you should change the indices. So instead of `line.split(':')[1], int(line.split(':')[2])` it's `line.split(':')[0], int(line.split(':')[1])`. You should change that too.

Comment: OHHH i understand now ! i have tried it before i dont understand why it iddnt work... oh well! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to split with

```
' : '
```

not

```
':'
```

Because if you split just with ':' your code will still keep the space after the word and before the number

Comment: Beat me to it. OP probably wants to use `.strip()` to get rid of any amount of whitespace.

Comment: `.strip()` doesn't remove white spaces, does it ?

Comment: Yup, it does. Both leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: ok do can you give me an idea how to integrate the .split to my string mot, nombre = line.split(' : ')[1], int(line.split(' : ')[2])   i guess i would have to strip the second argument its its the left one right?

Comment: Yup ! just use `.split(':')` with this one and you should be good !

Comment: Or else you can do like `mot, nombre = line.split(':')[1].strip(' '), int(line.split(':')[2].strip(' ')` removing all whitespaces

Comment: thanks its fixed i wasnt outputing the right sys.argv in this function. I understand now thanks you